# How to make a JTable resize as the windows does?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfreechart, windowbuilder

I'm making an application in eclipse with swing and jfreechart and I have the following problem:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot I have a frame with a few components. The problem is about the JTable, which always has the same size, no matter if I resize the window. I want the table to resize the same way other components do, like the ChartPanel at the right, and I don't know how to do it. The contentPane has a BorderLayout with three panels:

- The scrollPane for the JTable (WEST)
- The ChartPanel (CENTER)
- The panel for the buttons (SOUTH)

The code for the JTable creation is this:

```
private JTable getTasksTable() {
    if (tasksTable == null) {
        tasksTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "ID", "Duration", "Due-Date" }, 0) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }

        });

        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < tasksTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            tasksTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        }

        tasksTable.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(centerRenderer);
        tasksTable.getTableHeader().setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

        tasksTable.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        tasksTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    }
    return tasksTable;
}
```

Comment: Try a `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` holding the table & chart in `CENTER`.

Comment: I've tried both and they work better than what I had before but the problem is that the table is not getting resized. Also when i maximize the window there is an empty space in the table panel and i want the table to fit the whole panel.

Comment: You may have a nested `JPanel` with its default `FlowLayout` in the hierarchy; your fragment shows the table, but not the enclosing layout; please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: The only FlowLayout I have is at the pannel with the buttons. There are no more. The JTable is in a JScrollPane and I can't change the layout of that.

Comment: *"I can't change the layout of that."* Fine, whatever. You **can** post an MCVE. Do that.

Answer (score 1):

> The scrollPane for the JTable (WEST), The ChartPanel (CENTER), The panel for the buttons (SOUTH)

Well, the way a BorderLayout works is that:

1. the components in the WEST/EAST are sized at the preferred width of the component.
2. The component in the CENTER gets the remaining width.

So in your case the scrollpane is a fixed width and the width of the chart panel varies.

If you want both the scrollpane and the chart panel width to change as the frame size changes you need to use a different layout manager.

In this case you could use a panel with a `GridBagLayout` for the scrollpane and chart components. Then `GridBagLayout` will assign space at the preferred size of each component. Then you can specify the `weightx` constraint for each component to specify what percentage of extra space goes to each component as the frame with is increased.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the constraints and working examples to get you started.